# How to show input text that is clipped by padding?

Tags: css

If possible, I want to use padding just for aligning content, not for clipping it. In an input element, the content is the text, but I want to show the text that is "behind" the padding and "within" the input border.

For example the next input have padding in left and right:

```
<input value="parallelepiped" style="width: 100px; padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;">
```

And represented in plain text art, it clips the text "behind" the padding:

```
+---------------+
|      par      | // The padding clips the content of the input (undesired),
+---------------+ // in this example the text is aligned to the left.
```

The only change I want is to not clip the content:

```
+---------------+
|      parallele| // Not clipping the content of the input (desired effect),
+---------------+ // in this example aligned to the left (text-align: left;).

+---------------+
|lelepiped      | // Not clipping the content of the input (desired effect),
+---------------+ // in this example aligned to the right (text-align: right;).
```

The CSS property `text-overflow` was not helpful for this, neither was `overflow: visible;`.

**EDIT:** tryed to make the question more clear, due to the close appeals for not being clear or too broad.